# Is this sentence a mixed conditional or not?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, conditionals

Sarah had always dreamed of becoming a newscaster, but her parents urged her to study accounting instead. If only she had been true to her vision, she __________ on TV by now.

a. should be 
b. will possibly have been 
c. could possibly have been 
d. has possibly been

First, this is one of the English test in Korea. the answer is 'c'. But some say the answer is wrong, because this sentence is a mixed conditional, so right anwer is 'a'.
We are not native English speaker, so I want to know what native English speaker think of it. Which is correct between 'a' and 'c'?

And, can I use 'she would be on TV by now' or 'she might be on TV by now' or any suggestion? (sometimes modal verb is very tricky for non-native speaker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C is correct. The suggestion "would be" is quite natural, and "might be" could be used too.
 The A answer doesn't fit, because it is saying that it is appropriate now that she be on TV, but it isn't appropriate because she wasn't true to her vision.

I'm answering the questions within your post, but not the question in your title; I don't think in terms of numbered or mixed conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for your help~ ^^